How to include multiple Queries or Mutations in graphql with .net?
I declared (UserQuery) and (PostQuery) like the following:
namespace Blogging.API.Query
{
    [ExtendObjectType("Query")]
    public class UserQuery
    {
        [UseFiltering]
        [UseSorting]
        public async Task<List<User>> GetAll([Service] IUserResolver resolver)
        {
            return await resolver.GetAll();
        }

        public async Task<User> GetById([Service] IUserResolver resolver,int id)
        {
            return await resolver.GetById(id);
        }
    }
}


namespace Blogging.API.Query
{
    [ExtendObjectType("Query")]
    public class PostQuery
    {
        private readonly IPostResolver _postResolver;


        public PostQuery(IPostResolver postResolver)
        {
            _postResolver = postResolver;
        }

        [UseFiltering]
        [UseSorting]
        public Task<List<Post>> GetAll()
        {
            return _postResolver.GetAll();
        }

        public async Task<Post> GetById(int id)
        {
            return await _postResolver.GetById(id);
        }

        [UseFiltering]
        [UseSorting]
        public async Task<List<Post>> GetUserPosts(int userId)
        {
        
    return _=await _postResolver.GetUserPosts(userId);
        }

        
    }
}

and configuring them in program.cs as following:
builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType(q=>q.Name("Query"))
    .AddType<UserQuery>()
    .AddType<PostQuery>()
    .AddFiltering().AddSorting();

but when I open /graphql it gives me (NO SCHEMA), while if I removed one of those query classes it show the schema!
I want to know what is the problem with that.

Try to rename methods GetAll and GetById - both are available in query classes. GraphQL requires unique methods names.
